# Synchronized, clustered JMS application (Weblogic)

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, cluster-computing

First of all:

1. I am using **Weblogic 11g** with 3 *managed servers* and 3 *JMS servers* with a *distributed queue* and 3 *saf agents* (for sending the messages). The persistent store of all the JMS servers is stored in a network path - 3 files for 3 servers.
2. I need an application who sends a message to a queue (lets say `output.jms.q`) and then waits about 20 seconds to get the message from another queue (lets say `input.jms.q`)
3. Currently, the application sends the message to its destination and when it receiving the message, the message falls to one of the 3 queues inside the distributed queue.

In my code, If I send the message from Managed-Server-1, it will try to get the response in Managed-Server-1. (Using the `InitialContext()` constructor). that makes 66% of the messages unreachable!

I am aware of the `Forward Delay` option and I set it to like, 2 seconds. When I was in the development, it worked like charm! now, when I have a lot of clients testing it, It feels like the `Forward Delay` is not picking the right server.

When I shut down 2 of my Managed Servers - It works amazingly fast. but I am using just one machine instead of 3.

#### Could it be my setup?

For each Managed server there is a JMS server, and one Distributed Queue. I believe that for this thing, I only need **one** queue, that every JMS Server could connect to. something like a shared queue instead of distributed.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was using Distrubuted Topics. Weblogic 10.3.5+ supports replicating the messages between the servers.
yeah, its pretty lame.. but that's what I found.